# Arithmetic expression simplifier in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want of create simplifier of arithmetic expressions in Clojure, and I am new to this language.
So for ex.:

`in: "2x + 6y - (12 + (5x - 3y)) + 4" 
simplified: "- 3x + 9y - 8".`

So my attempt is to parse expression with regexp into hierarchical vector of nested expressions like this: 

`["5x-3y" "12 + <?>" "2x + 6y - <?> + 4"]  ;; <?> is evaluated item from 
previous step`

and then evaluate them in sequence.

I am feeling like it's hack, some advice would be helpful.

Comment: I'd use instaparse for that. Yet what exactly is the question here?  Do you face a problem or are you looking for advice to do that in a better fashion? Without the actual code it's hard to tell, but SO is about programming problems, so you might be better off asking this on codereview once the code is there?

Comment: Is this homework ?

Comment: nope, trying to study myself with a more practice.
Can share my code, if it will be helpfull.